# PHP - Outsource switch cases in different files

Tags: php, switch-statement

I want a switch-case instruction but outsource all the case-statements in diffenrent files.
Like this:

```
<?php
switch ($a) {
    foreach (glob("/path/*.php") as $filename) {
            include $filename;
        }
}
```

and in /path/ there are files like a.php and b.php with contents like

```
<?php
case 1:
    echo "hello";
    break;
```

How can I do this?

Edit:
I am using PHP7.1 if this is of interest.

Comment: I suspect you can't.

Comment: What errors do you get with the current code?

Comment: @mkaatman I get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'`

Comment: I can't imagine the use case for this. @MMM try putting it in `default: ` case and see what happens

Comment: Okay, I see what you're trying to do. That won't work. You could maybe do some voodoo with eval but it's a bad plan.

Comment: What is the value of `$a` suppose to be? Is `$a` suppose to be the file name?

Comment: @timothymarois No, `$filename` is the filename. `$a` is a value which is processed in the case-statements.

Comment: @MMM but you need an expression to make `$a` compared against something. Right now `$a` is utterly useless. What is `$a` comparing to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found for this is to change the switch-case to some if-statements:

```
$a = $_GET['something'];
foreach (glob("/path/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $filename;
}
```

And then in a.php

```
if ($a == 1) {
    echo "hello1";
}
```

in b.php

```
if ($a == 2) {
    echo "hello2";
}
```

and so on...

Comment: This looks more like a logical solution. I was going to update my answer with something similar, but I think you got it!

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet will fail instantly because it is not valid syntax. switch/case statements have a true/false expression system. You can use `in_array` to retrieve your results. (assuming `$a` is the file name you are looking for)

**Example:**

```
$files = ['/path/to/file.txt','/path/to/file2.txt'];

$a = '/path/to/file.txt';           
switch($a) {

    case in_array($a,$files) : 
      echo 'test';
    break;

    default :

}
```

**In your example, you can try:**

```
$location = glob("/path/");

switch($a) {

    case in_array($a,$location) : 
      include $a;
    break;

    default :

}
```

This is just example code of what you could do. There are many other ways to accomplish this, but you haven't given all the fact, such as `$a` values.

However, you may be wanting to run a whole set of files on different values of `$a`, another example:

```
switch($a) {
    case 'value_of_something_one' : 
      foreach (glob("/path/to/one") as $filename) {
        include $filename;
      } 
    break;

    case 'value_of_something_two' : 
      foreach (glob("/path/to/two") as $filename) {
        include $filename;
      } 
    break;

    default : 
}
```

Hope any of this helps.

*PHP Documentation: (switch/case)*
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: In my example `$a` has the value `1`. You example assumes that `$a` is the filename, right? Furthermore your solution would require to know all the filenames. I want to include alle the files in the dir without knowing them. But thx anyway!

Comment: @MMM ok, what are you comparing `$a` values with, if it has a value of `1` and only `1` then there is no expression needed, if the values change like 1,2,3 etc then where do they compare with, the directories? the file names?

Comment: For your edit: Thx, but that isn't the solution as well as the are is no `value_of_something_one` or two. There are `n` values, which cannot be fixed to a concrete number.

Comment: The values of `$a` compare the different strings. This could be `1` but `djfldkhfsl` as well.

Comment: @MMM ok, but does the value compare with any of the directories or file names themselves? How else do you know how to change which files you wish to run on the value of `$a`

Comment: No, it doesn't. I don't know this at all, so I include all files and want to check the values in `a.php`, `b.php` and so on.

Comment: @MMM Ok, sorry I mis-understood it then. I figured you wanted to display different files because of the value of `$a` described in your switch statement. But you want to run all the files, then check the values. So that's different entirely.